# copy and paste in new workbook reiteration

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste

I am trying to copy and paste the same worksheet (Overview) of a file (Connection Overview) to a new workbook and reiterate this action every time that a value in the worksheet "Overview" (value contained in the cell "Code") changes in accordance to a list of values (List) - changing therefore the output of the sheet "Overview".

In the end I would like to have the new workbook to be composed by sheets named by each code imputed in the cell "Code" and each sheet will therefore be a copy of the "Overview" worksheet with different numbers (depending on the code).

I was using this, but I clearly get stuck in the iteration:

```
Sub CopyItOver()
    x = 1
    For Each Lista In Range("List")
        Worksheets("Overview").Range("Code") = Lista
        Calculate
        Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add
        Workbooks("Connection Overview.xlsm").Worksheets("Overview").Copy
        NewBook.Sheets(“Sheet(x)”).Paste
        x=x+1
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Were you planning to name the new workbook before saving and closing it?

Answer (score 0):

When you copy a worksheet with no destination, the copy is created in a new blank workbook. All that remains is to take control of the new `ActiveWorkbook` and save it.

Right-click the worksheet's name tab and choose **View Code**. When the VBE opens, paste the following into the worksheet code pane titled something like *Book1 - Sheet1 (Code)*.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("Code")) Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo bm_Safe_Exit
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Dim fn As String, rng As Range
        fn = ThisWorkbook.Path & Chr(92) & "OVRVW_" & Format(Now, "yyyymmdd_hhmmss")
        Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Names("List").RefersToRange
        If Not IsError(Application.Match(Target.Value2, rng, 0)) Then
            Target.Parent.Copy
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=fn, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
            ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
        End If
    End If
bm_Safe_Exit:
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Tap <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> to return to the worksheet. Typing any of the values from the named **List** range should generate a new workbook.

The [Workbook.SaveAs method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841185.aspx) uses the supplied filename and the original workbook's path. The new workbook is saved as n .XLSX type workbook.

`Range("Code")` would be a single cell on the worksheet in question but there was no indication as to where `Range("List")` was so I defined its range from workbook scope.